# Checking a vector for duplicate frequency

Tags: c++, vector

What is the ***fastest way*** (execution) to find a repeated element in a vector, that repeats at-least **N** times.

I currently use this to check if a vector contains only a single repeated element:

```
vector<pair <unsigned __int16, unsigned __int16>> prevLocs;
//(removed)...
if (opts->prevLocs.size() >= 6 && adjacent_find(opts->prevLocs.begin(), opts->prevLocs.end(), std::not_equal_to<>()) == opts->prevLocs.end()) 
//(removed)...
if (opts->prevLocs.size() > 6)
  opts->prevLocs.erase(opts->prevLocs.begin());
opts->prevLocs.push_back(make_pair(x, y));
```

This tracks the last locations an entity has moved through and checks if its the same in the last couple of iteration to determine if it is stuck. But sometimes an entity is stuck but is stuck between positions, repeatedly going back and forth so my original code would no longer work.

So now I need to check for how many times a certain position is repeated in the last couple tracked to determine if it is just going back and forth, essentially stuck.

Comment: sort and count adjacents

Comment: Use an unordered_map to count each occurence of each value. Mission accomplished?

Comment: The best algorithm heavily depends on the nature of the data. How expensive are comparisons? Can the elements be hashed? How expensive is that? How many elements are in your vector?

Comment: You are asking for the fastest way. Please specify which speed is of the essence: implementation speed, execution speed, time to market. Also, since you ask for the fastest way and not for any way, please show the way you have already implemented, as a reference for what needs to be beaten. That would also avoid the impression that you actually just want somebody to implement it for you in any way and you do not really care about speed.

Comment: a typical mapreduce job, trying Spark library to generate the (key, value) pair with key the element in the vector and value the count?

Comment: updated question according to comments.